# How would I get the text of the newly checked item in a checked listbox with C#

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I'm using the ItemCheckEventArgs and from which I can get an index value, but from this value I'm not sure how to look up what the text is of whatever was checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ItemCheck event handler using ItemCheckEventArgs e you can retrive corresponding object

```
checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's some bare-bones code that should do the trick:

```
public void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var checkedListBox = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    var checkedItemText = checkedListBox.Items[e.Index].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`CheckedListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) class has a [`CheckedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) property.

```
private void WhatIsChecked_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Display in a message box all the items that are checked.

   // First show the index and check state of all selected items.
   foreach(int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
       // The indexChecked variable contains the index of the item.
       MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" + checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString() + ".");
   }

    // Next show the object title and check state for each item selected.
    foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {

        // Use the IndexOf method to get the index of an item.
        MessageBox.Show("Item with title: \"" + itemChecked.ToString() + 
            "\", is checked. Checked state is: " + checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString() + ".");
    }

}
```

Comment: This will give him all checked items. The OP specifically stated that he wants the text of the item that fired the event...

Comment: @Justin Niessner: True. And it also shows how to get only one element through the `Items` indexed property: `checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString()`. This prints the exact item enumerated, so the OP can see the different collections to play with the `CheckedListBox` object, and he can see how to get one. Two birds with one stone!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, put the following code

```
string text = (sender as CheckedListBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
```